# Pairwise distances between 3 random points in a ball

Tags: probability, density-function, geometry

Say I have a 3-D ball with radius $R$ and I randomly pick points from the volume of the ball.

If I randomly pick two points, the probability density function of inter-point distances $P(r_{12})$ is known and described by $P_{3}$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BallLinePicking.html).

Now I wish to randomly pick 3 points from the same ball. I'm interested in the probability density function of pairwise distances $P(r_{12}, r_{13}, r_{23})$. Is it possible to express this PDF using the $P_{3}$s mentioned above ? I know the result will not be $P_{3}(r_{12}) \times P_{3}(r_{13}) \times P_{3}(r_{23})$, because that would allow the triangle formed by these three points to be larger than is allowed to fit in the sphere.

Moving forward, would it be possible to express the PDF of pairwise distances for a general $N$-point polygon ? If not for a ball, could such expression be found for other box shapes ?